TSBD folder get created after adding WAF on my application
I am running an Angular application along with .Net core.
I realized that it automtically created TSBD folder when I inspected my application.
Because of this, somehow API not get called.
The application is running behind WAF and WAF is creating TSBD folder
Please help me how I can remove this folder.
